# ADAL authetication in Xamarin does not work for all office365 users

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to authenticate Xamarin app using office365 user. I registered the app in Aure Active Directory using my office365 user. The below code works perfectly fine for my office365 user. 
***But, as soon as I use any other office365 user, I get an error. Error details mentioned below***

***Error Message: The client has not listed any permissions for 'AAD Graph' in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Or, The admin has not consented in the tenant. Or, Check the application identifier in the request to ensure it matches the configured client application identifier. Please contact your admin to fix the configuration or consent on behalf of the tenant.***

I am not sure why the below logic works for my Office365 user account and does not work for the rest of office365 user accounts

```
string authority = "https://login.windows.net/common";
string graphResourceUri = "https://graph.windows.net";

var data = await auth.Authenticate(authority, graphResourceUri, clientId, returnUri);     

public async Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri)
{
    try
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);

        var controller = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
        var uri = new Uri(returnUri);
        var platformParams = new PlatformParameters(controller);
        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, uri, platformParams);
        return authResult;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var error = ex.Message.ToString();
        return null;
    }            
}
```

For signout functionality, I used the below code.

```
public void ClearAllCookies(string authority)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    authContext.TokenCache.Clear();            
    NSHttpCookieStorage CookieStorage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
    foreach (var cookie in CookieStorage.Cookies)
        CookieStorage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use your azure ad tenant instead of 'common' in your authority var. Like: 'https://login.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com' and pass in the user credentials in acquireTokenAsync(). Usually you need to pass in credentials to authenticate users, unless you're doing something different than I did, then I'm sorry I could not be more help.

Goodluck,

Comment: @EthanMelamed, Is it possible to pass username password to acquireTokenAsync() function as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, its just a different overload. It takes a UserCredentials object

Comment: @jay is your app registered as multi-tenant? and the users that it's not working for belonging to a different tenant? I think that it's working for your user becuase your user is in the same tenant as the one where app is registered (i.e. same Azure AD).. while the other users belong to a different Azure AD tenant (where admin consent hasn't happened yet)

Comment: @jay were able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @RohitSaigal, I was able to resolve the issue. I just asked my azure admin user to grant consent on behalf of all azure ad users for the application and then logic just worked fine for other users too.

Comment: that makes sense.. thanks for clarifying